# How to convert vb 6 ASCII decimal to char?

Tags: vb6, char, ascii

I have an ASCII decimal that i want to convert to a character in vb 6. Is it possible? if yes, how do i do that? In other words, how do i convert vb 6 ASCII decimal to vb 6 character?

```
Dim myChar As Char
Dim myBtye As byte
myChar =  ? myByte
```

Comment: Digging deep here; Wasn't it Chr(myByte)?

Comment: Wasn't it `Convert.ToChar()`?

Comment: Vb6 doesn't have a `Char` type. Are you actually using [Vb.Net]?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `Chr()` function is the slow Variant version of the deprecated `Chr$()` function.

Use `ChrW$()` instead, which was introduced over 15 years ago and is far faster.

Comment: `ChrW` did not *replace* `Chr`, it does a different conversion. `Chr` converts ANSI character codes (i.e. current Windows code page for non-Unicode programs) whereas `ChrW` converts Unicode character codes. They return the same character for codes less than 128, but **different** characters for larger code values. `Chr$` is not deprecated.

Comment: While they do different things there is seldom any good reason to go through the many gyrations involved in calling the `Chr$()` function.  It was most definately deprecated for general use long ago, and its only remaining purpose is the rare case where you want to specify ANSI character values above 127, which immediately get translated to their Unicode equivalents.  `Chr$()` is almost always the wrong tool.

Comment: It depends. I develop software for use internationally. My customers have to use characters above 128 to do anything in their native languages: accented characters, Chinese characters, etc. It's not a rare case for me.

Comment: I suppose there are special cases such as those you describe, except that you can just use the proper Unicode values for those characters and you save the extra conversion step implied inside the old `Chr$()` function.  Seems like a win-win to me, you can enter any character values required and you gain performance as well as making your code more self-documenting.  Use what you want, but the old ANSI function is meant to be quite secondary in use.

Answer (score 1):

```
Dim myByte As byte
Dim myChar As Char

myChar = Chr(myByte)
```

Chr is returning the string value of the given argument.

btw if you want to convert it back to ascii, you can use the Asc function.

Comment: There is no Char datatype in VB6, but your conversion to a single character String is correct.